# Extract path from generateUrl php symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Pretty basic question and I am sorry for that but I haven't find the answer to my problem yet

I have an `getArticleUrl` method that returns `$this->urlGenerator->generate($article);`

In my function, all I need to do is to append the query params to the `articleUrl`

```
    public function articleController(Request $request, string $uuid)
    {
        $queryParams = $request->query->all();

        $articleUrl = $this->getArticleUrl($uuid); 

        $redirectUrl = append somehow the query params; 

        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl, 301);
    }
```

I tried to use the generate method again but it didn't work as I supposed it already has the domain in it and it will duplicate it

```
$redirectUrl = $this->urlGenerator->generate($articleUrl, $queryParams, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

or perhaps I could get only the path from `$articleUrl` and call the `generate` for the new path and that could work, but it didn't

```
    public function articleController(Request $request, string $uuid)
    {
        $queryParams = $request->query->all();

        $articleUrl = $this->getArticleUrl($uuid);

        $parsed = parse_url($articleUrl);
        $path = $parsed['path'];

        if ($path) {
            $redirectUrl = $this->urlGenerator->generate($path, $queryParams);
        } else {
            $redirectUrl = $articleUrl;
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl, 301);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your problem, but if you already have some URL and just want to add the query parameters to it, you can use `http_build_query()` build in PHP function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `http_build_query`

```php
public function articleController(Request $request, string $uuid)
{
    $queryParams = $request->query->all();

    $articleUrl = $this->getArticleUrl($uuid);

    $redirectUrl = $articleUrl . '?' . http_build_query($queryParams);

    return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl, 301);
}
```

More Info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php